# LUKS partition disappeared after Windows installation

Tags: windows-10, grub, linux-mint, luks

I had a NVMe drive that had one partition with a LUKS encrpyted Linux Mint 19 and another partition with Windows 10. Both were able to boot (I had grub were I could select Linux or Windows to boot).
Then I re-installed Windows 10 on the second partition but this time I deleted the Win10 partition in the Windows installer and created a new one. At this point I think it created other partitions (I am not sure, maybe for UEFI boot or recovery).
After that I was able to boot Windows and thought I could just repair grub and should be able to boot both systems.

Now when I load grub, I have the same old boot options but when I try to boot the LUKS encrypted Linux I get the error `Encrypted LVM Boot fail (lvmetad not active)` and `volume group mint-vg not found`.

When I boot from a live USB-Linux:

```
root@mint:~# blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="2020-06-24-19-01-47-00" LABEL="Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon 64-bit" TYPE="iso9660" PTUUID="4089a39b" PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="4089a39b-01"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda2: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="1AC3-20ED" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="4089a39b-02"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="writable" UUID="7ea65c25-2113-4a05-af9f-a107e6a95879" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="4089a39b-03"
root@mint:~# ls -lh /dev/mapper/
total 0
crw------- 1 root root 10, 236 Apr  2 21:03 control
root@mint:~# ls -lh /dev/mapper/control 
crw------- 1 root root 10, 236 Apr  2 21:03 /dev/mapper/control
root@mint:~# /sbin/cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda3 crypt
Device /dev/sda3 is not a valid LUKS device.
```

Is anything lost now? I heard of some LUKS crypto headers, are they deleted now? Any way I could recover it?

UPDATE:

```
sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.75 GiB, 1863593984 bytes, 3639832 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 28.92 GiB, 31029460992 bytes, 60604416 sectors
Disk model: DataTraveler 3.0
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x4089a39b

Device     Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *          0  3876543  3876544  1.9G  0 Empty
/dev/sda2           648     8583     7936  3.9M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sda3       3878912 60604415 56725504 27.1G 83 Linux
```

When booting from the live system it doesn't recognize my NVMe drive.

```
root@mint:~# lshw -class storage -class disk
  *-usb                     
       description: Mass storage device
       product: DataTraveler 3.0
       vendor: Kingston
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@2:1.1
       logical name: scsi16
       version: 1.10
       serial: 80C5F289B108E2C1986B01EA
       capabilities: usb-3.20 scsi emulated scsi-host
       configuration: driver=usb-storage maxpower=504mA speed=5000Mbit/s
     *-disk
          description: SCSI Disk
          product: DataTraveler 3.0
          vendor: Kingston
          physical id: 0.0.0
          bus info: scsi@16:0.0.0
          logical name: /dev/sda
          version: PMAP
          serial: 8E02CC51F928
          size: 28GiB (31GB)
          capabilities: removable
          configuration: ansiversion=6 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
        *-medium
             physical id: 0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             size: 28GiB (31GB)
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: signature=4089a39b
  *-raid
       description: RAID bus controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 17
       bus info: pci@0000:00:17.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: raid msix pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:b4200000-b4207fff memory:b4209000-b42090ff ioport:4080(size=8) ioport:4088(size=4) ioport:4060(size=32) memory:b4100000-b417ffff
```

(I am not using RAID)

UPDATE: I forgot to mention that the system did a firmware/BIOS update after rebooting.

Comment: Pretty sure `sda` is your USB drive. To see partitions, use `fdisk -l`.

Comment: You are right, I added the output to the question. It doesn't show my drive at all. When booting, it gets recognized (when I switch to one time boot menu I can boot into windows and I can select grub)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to switch the SATA to AHCI mode in my BIOS settings because either the installation or the firmware updated switched it to RAID mode.
After that everything worked as expected.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).